# Accessing classes have specific annotations in Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven-plugin

I want to use the Maven plugin to access classes that have specific annotations, how can I do that?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Parameter(defaultValue = "NotSet")
private String forecast;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}")
private MavenProject mavenProject;

@Override
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    getLog().debug("Executing");
    // Accessing the maven project and getting the classes
    getLog().debug("Stopping");
}
```

I try to use the reflections library but it seems doesn't work for the Maven project which I want to access.

Have you any ideas?

SOLVED with:

```
@Mojo(name = "generator", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE, requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE)
```

AND:

```
List<String> classpathElements = null;
    try {
        classpathElements = mavenProject.getCompileClasspathElements();
        List<URL> projectClasspathList = new ArrayList<URL>();
        for (String element : classpathElements) {
            try {
                projectClasspathList.add(new File(element).toURI().toURL());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new MojoExecutionException(element + " is an invalid classpath element", e);
            }
        }

        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(projectClasspathList.toArray(new URL[0]));
        // ... and now you can pass the above classloader to Reflections
        Class clazz = Class.forName("com.example.demo.DemoApplication", true, loader);
        Arrays.stream(clazz.getAnnotations())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(loader);
        reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(CuspidsApi.class)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new MojoExecutionException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (DependencyResolutionRequiredException e) {
        new MojoExecutionException("Dependency resolution failed", e);
    }
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/21144042), and then edit your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.